# How to pass an HTML string in a Query String in IOS

Tags: html, ios, query-string

I have a simple IOS application that I created for consultants where I work. It has a custom keyboard with notation that they use that includes superscript and subscript characters. The easiest way that I found to handle those characters was using `HTML` and a `WebView`, which works just fine.

I am now attempting to send this information to a web application that will insert it into a SQL database. Sending all of the other information works just fine, until I get to the transcript with `HTML` in it. I am encoding each of the values that I send through the query string with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` but the query string fails when HTML elements are included. I believe this is due to the `/` that is not removed during the escape encoding. For example the HTML break tag becomes `%3Cbr%20/%3E`. So the `<` `>` and space are replaced, but not the `/`.

Should I be using a different method? Is there an easy way to send HTML over Query String? Am I correct that the `/` character is what is breaking my query string?

Here is the code I have now:

```
NSString *datePE =[dateString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *studentPE =[student stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *teacherPE =[teacher stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *transcriberPE =[transcriber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *vrPE =[vrTextField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *totalTimePE =[totalTimeString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *transcriptPE =[transcriptString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dateQS=%@&studentQS=%@&teacherQS=%@&transcriberQS=%@&vrQS=%@&totalTimeQS=%@&transcriptQS=%@",datePE ,studentPE,teacherPE,transcriberPE,vrPE,totalTimePE, transcriptPE];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest
           requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.domain.net/folder/subfolder/Default.aspx?"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                             delegate:self
                                     startImmediately:YES];
```

Comment: Why don't you send it via POST? A GET request doesn't seem like the right place to send that kind of data...

Comment: I am using POST as the HTTPMethod, so I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Then you can just encode the string as `NSData` and send it in the body. So you you don't need to worry about the special characters. You can use `[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to convert your string to an `NSData` object.

Comment: Ok, so I think I am passing it in the body now, but the page isn't picking up anything from the query string. I've updated the original post with my current code.